# Git checkout from repository on GitHub into an existing local repository based on SVN

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github

I recently migrated a project to GitHub from Subversion but the current working local directory is still an SVN local repository. Due to complicated reasons it wouldn't be good to make a new git clone local repository so is there any way to check out the git repository from GitHub?

Right now it's giving me the error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)
```

Obviously since I'm not using a git local repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `git init` in your Subversion working directory will make it a git repository.
2. `git remote add origin <url>`, where `<url>` is the HTTPS or SSH path from GitHub, will connect your local repository to GitHub.
3. `git fetch origin` will update your local Git repository with all its history from GitHub
4. `git reset origin/master` will point your local master branch to the latest master from origin, without changing of your files.

At this point `git status` will show you any differences between your local working directory and what's on GitHub.

Comment: GitHub also supports using Subversion as a client: https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your core issue is that you try to keep a Subversion and a Git repository in sync in such way, that Git should be only an additional view on to your Subversion repository. If this is the case SubGit might be a solution: It provides a Git mirror of a  Subversion repository so you could just stick to Subversion on your machine while having also the additional Git repository.

Comment: If the project was indeed migrated to GitHub, then SubGit is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an "SVN checkout" of a git repository.

In git, cloning a repository includes all of its history. git tools rely on this to perform their functions. In SVN, all the history is on the server and the local side is just a working copy.

You're going to have to do a `git clone`. The closest knockoff to how SVN works would be to do a clone with --depth=1, but the resulting checkout would be pretty badly crippled.

If you were to want to do the inverse of what you're asking - that is to say, you want to use a local git client with an upstream SVN repository - the answer would be `git-svn`.

If you just want to minimize the amount redownloaded - you only said "complicated reasons", so I can't reason about your motives - just keeping the local files isn't going to be enough. As I mentioned, git stores not only the latest version of the files but also every past revision. That past version information will have to be downloaded no matter what you do.